# ios triggering activity indicator in tableview while data loads and hiding proto cells

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, interface-builder

So I have an activity indicator in my tableview but the problem is that when I trigger it to start and stop I also have the prototype cell showing in the background which makes the UI look bad. I just want the tableview to be a solid color while I make my network call with my activity indicator on top. How can I make the separating lines disappear while my data is loading? I tried changing toggle the hidden property on the cell in interface builder but no success there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just add this line

```
tableView.tableFooterView = UIView()
```

Comment: That seems to do it thanks. Why in the world would you set tableFooterView though? Setting it to an empty UIView() makes sense to me now that I see it, but why footer?

Comment: The cells will be displayed - whether you have data or not - so a better solution might be to display something there to show that data will be coming.  A label saying "Loading ..." or something like that?

Comment: Because the table thinks there is a footer to show, it doesn't display any cells before you explicitly ask for.